# Linux Repository Error

Tags: rhel, mount, apache-httpd, rpm, repository

I created a network repository for the hosts that hasn't got internet connection.So the environment has 1 repo server and 1 client. (It's in the test stage so both host can go to internet). I did make a filesystem and mount it on the path /AllRepositories/Centos7. Than I tried to download the rpm packages to here. I also did the requirement steps createrepo / createrepo --update. The problem is, the client host can't install packages from this host.

Server config

```
createrepo /var/www/html/AllRepositories/Centos7
```

I download all packages with this command;

```
repoquery -a | xargs repotrack -a x86_64 -p .
```

I update db with;

```
createrepo --update /var/www/html/AllRepositories/Centos7
```

My client's .repo config is

```
[RemoteRepoDisk]
name=Remote Repository Disk
baseurl=http://<ip address>/AllRepositories/Centos7/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

So, when I try to download from client, I first type "yum repolist all" and my client see  that repository is enabled and there are 9911 packets available. Than, when I type, "yum install nano" for example, it brings the packet download page.

```
Total download size: 440 k
Installed size: 1.6 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]:
```

When I type y, it says that

```
Downloading packages:
Delta RPMs disabled because /usr/bin/applydeltarpm not installed.
nano-2.3.1-10.el7.x86_64.rpm   FAILED
http://<<ip address>>/AllRepositories/Centos7/nano-2.3.1-10.el7.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden0 B  --:--:-- ETA
Trying other mirror.


Error downloading packages:
  nano-2.3.1-10.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

But from server, when I try to download the rpm packages to a normal directory(not mounted path), my client can see and download the packets.How  can I download packets from clients from the mounted path?

**UPDATE:**

In error logs of httpd:

```
(13)Permission denied: [client 10.0.6.180:52939] AH00035: access to /AllRepositories/centos7/nano-2.3.1-10.el7.x86_64.rpm denied (filesystem path '/var/www/html/AllRepositories/centos7/nano-2.3.1-10.el7.x86_64.rpm') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
```

It says that my search permissions are missing. I did some research for error 13. It indicates a filesystem permission problem.  So I give chmod 755 to the directory /var/www/html and restart httpd but still it gives the same error.

---

Comment: SELinux may be interfering with your RPM files: https://serverfault.com/questions/697752/yum-repo-responding-with-errno-14-http-error-403-forbidden

Comment: Your web server prevents from downloading rpm packages from repository for permission issues.

Comment: @mimish yes it gives permission error. So I gave 755 to the /var/www/html directory but still it gives the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned off selinux after giving the permissions to directories with setenforce 0 and it worked.